# Reading a newick format phylogeny in r using caper

Tags: r, phylogeny

I desire to perform comparative analysis using independent contrasts which I believe can be done in ape. I have a phylogeny of the cat family in newick format, and when I try to read in the file I get the error below:

> phy<-read.tree("phylogeny.txt")
>                                                                               Error in if (sum(obj[[i]]$edge[, 1] == ROOT) == 1 && dim(obj[[i]]$edge)[1] >  : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Could anyone very kindly perhaps explain to me what this error means?

Kind regards,
K.

Edit, the newick string is posted below:

((((Tiger_108,Snow leopard_024),(Jaguar_026,(Lion_127,Leopard_028))),(Clouded leopard_25,(Sunda clouded leopard_036))),((Serval_001,(Caracal_020,African golden cat_002)),(((Pampas cat_3,(TigrinaCA_13,(TigrinaSA_6,(Geoffroy's cat_003,Kodkod_003)))),(Andean mountain cat_1,(Margay_022,Ocelot_006))),(((Bobcat_004,(Canadian lynx_3,(Eurasian lynx_001,Iberian lynx_2))),(Marbled cat_005,(Bay cat_2,Asian golden cat_8))),(((Jungle cat_20,(Black-footed cat_0006,(Sand cat_8,((European wild cat_007,Domestic cat_4804),(African wild cat_0004,Chinese desert cat_5))))),(Pallas cat_65,(Rusty-spotted cat_1,(Flat-headed cat_6,(Fishing cat_02A,Asian leopard cat_054))))),(Cheetah_234,(Jaguarundi_5,Puma_28)))))));

Comment: You'll need to show us what your phylogeny newick string looks like. Does it have singleton nodes (nodes with only one descendant)?

Comment: Hello. I have added the newick string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your newick tree has singleton nodes, which `read.tree` cannot deal with. Install the `phytools` library and use the `read.newick` function instead.

Note that you probably need to collapse your singleton nodes using `collapse.singles()` to perform any analyses

```
library(phytools)
tree = read.newick("phylogeny.txt")
# Read 1 item
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. :) I just need to figure out now how to actually do the analyses, but I am sincerely very appreciative that you have helped because before I could not even start!

Comment: @KB2 You can start by looking at the `pic` function in the `ape` package. `ape` is where you will find most of your tools for doing phylogenetic analyses.

Comment: If I wanted to analyse home range size compared to average annual rainfall, temperature and elevation (for example), how would I do that using pic(x, phy, scaled = TRUE, var.contrasts = FALSE,
    rescaled.tree = FALSE) ?

Comment: @KB2 Yes, that should work. Just make sure `x` is in the right format; you should probably name the values of `x` corresponding to the tip labels associated with the values.

Comment: I do not really understand. Would 'x' be 'Tiger' for example, where would I tell r to look at data on rainfall?

Comment: You give it a vector of the rainfall values, then you assign the names to vector using `names(x)`. That way you can have the values associated with the proper species name.

Comment: Thank you for the help. So for assigning a vector it should look like this?x<-(60,
    60,
    60,
    60,
    60,
    60,
    56,
    56,
    56,
    56,
    56,
    56,
    56,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    43.1,
    100,
    100,
    100,
    100,
    100,
    40,
    40,
    40,
    40,
    13,
    13,
    13,
    13, etc
  I kept getting this error code:

Comment: Error: unexpected ',' in "x<-(60,"
>     70).6,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104590/discussion-between-kb2-and-cactuswoman).